# Gradle: Pass mvn credentials via gradle command line

Tags: gradle

I've my build.gradle something like below

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    credentials {
        username "$artificatoryMvnUser"
        password "$artificatoryMvnPassword"
    }
    url 'https://artifactory.somedomain.com/awesome-maven-local'
}
```

I would like to pass the maven credentials via gradle command line.

**What I've tried**
Passing the command line argument via -P option,
`/opt/gradle-2.13/bin/gradle -PartificatoryMvnUser=someUser -PartificatoryMvnPassword=somePassword`

Did not work. I've tried searching google and stackoverflow but couldn't get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: * What went wrong:
16-Oct-2017 10:30:20 A problem occurred evaluating root project 'some-project'.
16-Oct-2017 10:30:20 > No such property: artificatoryMvnUser for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated

Comment: Hmm.. I've just checked you code and it runs just fine.

Comment: Strange!!! i just tried again now and it works. Not sure what was the issue :)

Comment: If you've got your passwords encrypted in a maven `settings.xml` you might be able to adapt [this code](https://github.com/jelmerk/maven-settings-decoder/blob/master/src/main/java/org/github/jelmerk/maven/settings/Decorder.java) to decrypt and share the same file